# How to use react-query with the normalpeoplepicker control?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-query

We are using React Query for all queries in a React web application.
One page has a NormalPeoplePicker:

```
<NormalPeoplePicker 
  aria-label={nomPropriete}
  onResolveSuggestions={onFilterChanged}
  pickerSuggestionsProps={suggestionProps}
  className={"ms-PeoplePicker"}
  key={"normal"}          
  removeButtonAriaLabel={"Remove"}
  onChange={onSelChange}          
  resolveDelay={300}
  disabled={disable}
  itemLimit={maxItems}
  data-testid={nomPropriete}                      
/>
```

The onResolveSuggestions method is used to display suggestions based on the text typed by the user in the control.

```
const onFilterChanged = (filterText: string, currentPersonas?: IPersonaProps[], limitResults?: number): IPersonaProps[] | Promise<IPersonaProps[]> => {
    //get data from filterText

    //return data
};
```

The problem is since I am using react query to get the data like this...

```
const [filterString, setFilterString] = React.useState<string>("");
const { data, refetch } = useUserGatewayHttp().getFilteredUsers(filterString);
```

...and like this...

```
const getFilteredUsers = (filter: string): UseQueryResult<userInfo[], Error> => {   
    return useQuery({
        queryKey: ["FilteredUsers", filter],
        queryFn: async (): Promise<userInfo[]> => {
            return await graphRepository.getFilteredUsers(filter);
        },
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        enabled: true
    });
};
```

...and like this...

```
const onFilterChanged = (filterText: string, currentPersonas?: IPersonaProps[], limitResults?: number): IPersonaProps[] | Promise<IPersonaProps[]> => {
   setFilterString(filterText);

   return data;
};
```

...how can I be sure I will have the data before the end of the onFilterChanged method?
I tried using refetch but I have the same problem.

I also tried using QueryClient fetchQuery like this:

```
const { graphRepository } = useRepositoryDependency();

const fetchFilteredUsers = (filter: string): Promise<userInfo[]> => { 
   return queryClient.fetchQuery({
      queryKey: ["FilteredUsers", filter],
      queryFn: async (): Promise<userInfo[]> => {
         return await graphRepository.getFilteredUsers(filter); //Does not work with this line
      }
  });
};
```

The fetchFilteredUsers is not executed when it contains a call to the graphRepository method.

If you have any idea or suggestion on which approach to use, please tell me know!
Thanks a lot!